# how to separate strings from descending xml nodes get by to_literal function from xml::xmllib module in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I have XML structure in like this:

```
<A>
  <B>One</B>
  <C>Two</C>
  <D>
     <E>Three</E>
     <F>Four</F>
     ...
  </D>
  ...
</A>
```

Structure is big, complex and I know only begining, i.e: '/A'

and code in perl like this:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml = $parser->parse_file($file);
print $xml->find('/A')->to_literal;
```

gives me result:

```
OneTwoThreeFour
```

If I use code like:

```
print join (" ", map { $_->to_literal } $xml->findnodes('/A/descendant::*'));
```

I get:

```
One Two ThreeFour Three Four
```

I need unique and sparate with withespaces values, i.e.:

```
One Two Three Four
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synopsis of [XML::LibXML::Node](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode) gives you a hint:

```
@nodes = $node->findnodes( $xpath_expression );
$result = $node->find( $xpath );
```

So use the `findnodes` method to receive a **list** of results. Also, you want to select the children of the `A` element, change the XPath expression to fit:

```
my @children_literal_text = map { $_->to_literal } $xml->findnodes('/A/*');
# ('One', 'Two')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926589/how-to-select-all-leaf-nodes-using-xpath-expression

Comment: nice, but what if leaf node does not contain string? i.g. <D>five<H></H></D> ? With this solution I lost some data...

Comment: I'm tired of the question changing constantly. Good day.