# How to get all node values from a feed

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

I have following feed:

```
$result = apiCall('somevalue', 'somevalue', array('somevalue' => $some_string));
```

which is in json format. I can very easy to turn it into xml with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

The xml feed looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
    <response>
        <status>success</status>
        <code>200</code>
        <message>
            <a>
                <g>val1</g>
                <b>val2</b>
                <c>val3</c>
            </a>
            <d>
                <e>val4</e>
                <f>val5</f>
            </d>
        </message>
    </response>
```

Is there a simple and fast way to get all node values (i.e. val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 and so on)?

Comment: Hint: xpath.  Also, please [read this important post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135887) about a problem that may be impacting your ability to get good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select all leaf nodes using XPath expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926589/how-to-select-all-leaf-nodes-using-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something that I think will work:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<response>
    <status>success</status>
    <code>200</code>
    <message>
        <a>
            <g>val1</g>
            <b>val2</b>
            <c>val3</c>
        </a>
        <d>
            <e>val4</e>
            <f>val5</f>
        </d>
    </message>
</response>
EOD;

$output = array();
$test = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$result = $test->xpath('message//*[not(*)]');
while(list(, $node) = each($result)) {
    array_push($output, (string) $node);
}

var_dump($output);

?>
```

I haven't tested it on a lot of things (attributes), but on the provided input it gives the expected output.
What it does is like you can see an xpath expression that retrieves any child of the `message` node.

Of course, since there are also nodes with even more childnodes in it (like `a`and `d`) we need to filter those out. So the last part containing the `not(*)` means that it will only select those childs which do not have any sub child.

I'm not an XPATH expert so there are probably faster ways of achieving this, but I think this will do.

Comment: Dimitri, instead of `var_dump($output)` using following code:

`for ($i = 0; $i <  count($output); $i++) {
    $key=key($output);
    $val=$output[$key];
    if ($val<> ' ') {
       echo $val ." <br> ";
       }
     next($output);
    }`

Gives me what I need - all values of nodes. `var_dump($output);` outputs the array `array(50) { [0]=> string(7) "value1" [1]=> string(16)` etc.

Comment: The `var_dump($output);` was obviously only a test case to dump the contents (so you and I could see the result and verify if it works). The implementation (and what you do with the output) is obviously your task, not mine. :) The real parsing work is done on the lines above.

Comment: yes, your way is better if you want to assign specific variable to values based on their key.

Comment: I'm having the idea that you don't understand the provided code. `var_dump($output);` or your output makes really no difference to your question of how to parse this XML. The parsing is already done in the `while(list(, $node) = each($result)) { ... }` above.

Answer (score 1):

I came to a similar conclusion like Dimitri M, it's based on a previous Q&A [*How to select all leaf nodes using XPath expression?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926589/how-to-select-all-leaf-nodes-using-xpath-expression).

Leaf-Nodes are the outermost nodes, which are those you're looking for, here the `text()` nodes in your case.

```
$nodeValues = array_map(
    'trim',
    simplexml_load_string($xml)->xpath('message//*[not(*)]/text()')
);
```

Given that `$xml` is your XML input, `$nodeValues` is then an array of all those strings that represent the node values you're looking for. Exemplary:

```
Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val2
    [2] => val3
    [3] => val4
    [4] => val5
)
```

Comment: Note: This returns the same compared to the other answer for the XML in question. I also *"cast"* via `trim` here in the `array_map` operation. So I have casting to string, too. You need that to obtain the concrete string values with SimpleXML.

Comment: I noticed it just after posting. My excuses. ^^