# XSLT: select all nodes without inner elements and without attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

How to select all nodes without inner elements and without attributes in .xml with unknown structure?

Comment: start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926589/how-to-select-all-leaf-nodes-using-xpath-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPATH expression to find elements without subelements  nor attributes is: 
//*[not(*|@*)]
You will get only elements with text(). Code that gets names of those elements is below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[not(*|@*)]"/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*">
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It should be //*[not(*|@*)] , not  //[not(|@*)]